# IDE independent mercurial repository

Tags: netbeans, mercurial

I've just recently started using Mercurial and would like to keep my projects as independent from IDE as possible.

Therefore, I would like to only include my src, test src, and doc directory in the repository.
I've managed to only book these directories into the repository by ignoring all project related files.

The problem is that when I then clone it onto another system, Netbeans 7 wants to create a new project from these files. It does so by creating the project file inside of the repo instead of on the cloned name, since it cannot create a project on a directory that already exists.

Is there a standard way of booking in these folders and then when cloning them to create a project from them?

Answer (score 0):

What about creating the project in Netbeans first and the cloning the files into it?

To avoid Mercurial complaining about the clone destination not being empty, use init + pull in the project directory instead of clone, this is equivalent:

```
$ cd myproject
$ hg init
$ hg pull -u http://example.org/myrepo
```

You could also just clone into a separate directory and then move all files (including the hidden .hg directory) into the Netbeans project. You could even just move the .hg directory, because that’s really all that Mercurial cares about.

Although actually I’m surprised you can’t start a project that is already on the file system. I’m not familiar with Netbeans, but can’t you import an existing project from the file system?

Comment: I've tried to create the Netbeans project first, then clone into it, but it does not want to clone into the project directory since the clone directory has the same name as the project. If I give it a different name, the source folders don't link up correctly.

Comment: I updated the answer with a description how to circumvent the directory not empty error message.